# Postgres array column accidentally made to text, how can I convert it back to a text array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's a column in my database that's a text column that should be an array column. All of the values of that column are valid Postgres arrays (since they were taken as text values from a Postgres array column) with format like `{valuea,valueb}`. I need them as array values however, so how do I convert them back to array values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ALTER TABLE.. ALTER COLUMN` with the `USING` option

```
alter table t alter column col type text[] using col::text[];
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a4a68e994e2fecf9fa7aba1620a56478)